# Laravel : use undocumented methods or not?

Tags: laravel

I want to know if there is any risk of using undocumented Laravel methods .
such as `latest()` , `oldest()` ,`attribute()` . is there any reason not to use theme ?

Comment: You may use them (IMO). If for some reason those goes removed then you are able to implement them in your extended model.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong way to use any method if it works. You may use them till it's not deprecated and maintained by Laravel.

If you want to stick with Laravel's latest documentation, it's always up to you.

> I prefer to follow Laravel Documentation in ongoing projects.